# HP Fingerprint sensors

Tags: fingerprint-reader, lsusb

I'm trynig to get fingerprint reader to work. `lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc.
```

I've looked at https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:06cb-00c9 which shows no drivers.

Does this mean hope is lost?

Comment: Just to note that the list linked by @linuxbuild below has since been updated and now lists this device as supported, at least in the development version.  I've also got one but haven't figured out how to get it working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, libfprint doesn't support your device currently: https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html